# Mantras to attract a male

Tags: mantras

I watched the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lRjGsTUUlQ&sns=em) by Dr. Pillai and two others explaining that chanting *AIM* will bring about a male companion, as opposed to *KLEEM* attracting females. This intrigued me.

I want to know why this information isn't prevalent. When I research about *AIM*, it states that it brings about wisdom, knowledge, education. I can't find any reputable information that *AIM* attracts men except from this one video. Why?

In any case, I would like to chant this mantra. How should I chant?  *OM AIM* does not roll off my tongue. Can I chant *OM SHREEM BRZEE AIM NAMAHA*?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. Your question is somewhat off-topic for the site where we do no discuss for personal wants or greed because such questions may sound offensive to some and for others it may be opinion based so I'll be closing your question until you make it meaningful for other users.

Comment: btw there is a story in the Taittiriya Samhita (II. iv. 12.) showing the adverse effects of not intoning a mantra correctly. A god, Tvashtri, in pronouncing the word Indra-satru, he accented the first instead of the last syllable. In short, instead of taking away power from Indra, he gave Indra more power.

Comment: absurd censorship.  All kinds of unscientific things are present in the scriptures - why declare this question off-topic seems to be the whim of the censors.  ALL CENSORSHIP BECOMES TYRANNICAL.

Comment: There are many such mantras given in the Tantras. You need to find the most suitable one for u and then hv to practice it as prescribed.

Answer (score 6):

1. Mantras are to be given by a learned guru and are not to be openly chanted.
2. Mantras are given only to deserving people (those who have graduated to a certain level of spirituality through observance of certain discipline prior)
3. What Dr. Pillai is doing is wrong and will have negative effects. You should also not take refuge in false gurus who do not respect the sanctity of mantras. A mantra is effective only if the corresponding rules are followed.
4. Aim is the saraswati(learning) beeja not kAma (desire) beeja. And as I mentioned in a previous response/comment, there is no such thing as "brzee".
5. For a mantra to be effective, the chanter also has to follow certain rules such as celibacy, strict diet, sleeping on the floor etc. This may not be possible for all.
6. Above all, women are not supposed to chant mantras. They should not even hear certain mantras when they are pregnant or menstruating. So it is impossible for a true guru to initiate a woman into a mantra.

One of the reasons one is unable to pronounce the mantras (and chanting with proper intonation is supreme because of the sound vibrations set forth by the mantra) properly is being a meat-eater. Meat thickens the tongue and renders it difficult to pronounce certain words. There are other reasons such as influence of one's native language etc.

Therefore, people 
who are constrained by all the above, should keep chanting "namah sivaaya" or " sri krishnaaya namaha"

There are no restrictions to chanting the names of the lord except that one must be clean (in body and mind) when chanting. It is better to chant while sitting in a cleaned, quiet place. Make sure you sit on a mat and not on the floor when you chant. Alternatively, every morning, after a bath, face the Sun God and pray to Him in your own language. Use the same prayer every day. All your righteous desires will be fulfilled. Good luck. Remember respect for the divine is paramount.

Comment: Special women known as bramhavadinis are allowed to perform all things that a male bramhin/dwija does(chanting and listening vedas). Bramhavadinis are trained by special bramhin (acharyas) and follow certain set of rules like they live in mathas or in the house of acharya. The only exception to bramhavadini's is in their menstrual cycle.

Comment: @Yogi I have not heard of any of this being sanctioned by bastions of Hindu dharma like peethadhipatis of sankara mathas.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/rules-for-wearing-yagyopavit-by-women-yes-it-is-possilbe check this out

Comment: @Yogi I do not subscribe to it. I'd rather follow Sankaracharya than others in matters pertaining to dharma. 2ndly,what you describe seems to have been prevalent millennia ago. I too acknowledged in a answers/comments that women of ancient/pre-historic times were able to sandhya etc. but lost the ability to do so after being attributed prayaschitta for Indra's brahmahatya pAtaka. Therefore, women in current times cannot do sandhya or recite vedas. Brahmavadinis are not a good counter-example for this.

Answer (score 6):

Aim is a bija (seed) word which should only be intoned when given directly by an enlightened guru to a disciple. The 'power' of the vibration is only gained when the sound intonation is received directly from one's guru.

It is also used in certain prayers in pujas - by priests and sadhus who are trained in proper pronunciation.

There are mantras for a woman to obtain a husband (Atharva Veda Book II) or to win a man's love (Atharva Veda Book VI). If one wishes to use these mantras, they should be done with the help of a brahmin priest who is a priest of the Atharva Veda (brahmins specialize in different Vedas).

To intone a mantra without proper training will result in no results or negative results. If someone sings a song completely off-key but knows all the words, are the vibrations that reach your ear the same as a person professionally trained as a singer?

It is best to stay away from people in the West who profess to Westerners that they are experts in mantras.