# Why are women not allowed to chant the Gayatri mantra?

Tags: belief, women, prayer, gayatri-mantra

Many say that girls/women are not supposed to chant the Gayatri mantra. Is there any specific reason for this? Since it is one of the most powerful mantras, would it be good if women also chant the Gayatri mantra?

Comment: From where you got that women aren't allowed? (who/which scripture says?)

Comment: I might not be able to quote any references in particular. However it is normally advised not to tell gayatri mantra. Hence i need more inputs/clarification on this.

Comment: I know of no scripture that says that women are not supposed to chant Gayatri. Probably said by some local men with no knowledge of scripture and use it to keep themselves superior.

Comment: Women are not allowed to chant any mantra, let alone gayatri. I am a woman and I have no problem with this rule. No saviours are needed in this matter. To answer your question, every mantra is associated with what is called adhikara which is born of centuries and generations of mutations of the jeeva. So, some may have certain adhikaras while others don't (for e.g. sudras are not initiated into the gayatri). It does not mean that sudras are less. Since they too have a right to attain the supreme like everyone else, rishis and scriptures have given them too their own methods. 1/2

Comment: Like performing namaskara to Sun God. However, those intiiated into the gayatri must perform sandhya vandanam to attain the same results. One need not compete with the other. Similar rules apply to women. Another reason is, whenever someone is initiated into a mantra, it must be performed without interruption. Women cannot adhere to this rule because of the interruptions caused by menstruation. Now, if you start arguing that menstruation is not an obstacle and god can be worshipped during this time, I have nothing to say except scripture forbids it. 2/2

Comment: Women in ancient India used to perform Sandhya rites.  In Srimad Ramayana there is reference to this aspect. संध्या काल मनाः श्यामा ध्रुवम् एष्यति जानकी |
नदीम् च इमाम् शिव जलाम् संध्या अर्थे वर वर्णिनी ||  

(Sundara Kanda 14th Sarga 49th Sloka)   "The ever youthful one with the best complexion, Seetha interested in the rites of Sandhya time will definitely come to this river with the auspicious water for Sandhya rite." .  However, it is difficult to say why they stopped doing so now.

Comment: I read somewhere that in ancient period this mantra used to be known as SAVITR mantra available in Gayatri Chandas (meter).  Later on it is being called Gayatri mantra.

Comment: @moonstar2001, you should post as an answer. Many of the discussions (about *Dharma*) are just based on dry scriptures. The core explanation is missed and hence the charm. The term *"Adhikara"* mentioned is the key to your explanation. If you answer, you may also add that as the *Adhikara* decreases, the tendency of *Bhakti marg* increases, which is the easiest path among all. A woman in menstruation is called *Rajaswala*. During this time the *RajoGuna* is max(responsible for fruitful actions). A devotee tends to ask returns for worship to God. This leads to sense oriented(*Rajasic*) worship.

Comment: @iammilind Keshav will simply delete my answer because there is no quote from "dry scripture" :-)

Comment: @moonstar2001, a moderator won't delete an answer, because scriptural reference lacking. There are many such answers even from new joiners. What to say about the reputed & well-received member like you? AFAIK, your answers are the best in English (at least better to me) and contains sensible content. What you commented above is truth. The keyword *Adhikara* alone holds it strong! It won't be fair for the community, if intellectuals refrain just because of 'deletion' (fruitful action!). BTW, such restrictions are tricky today as more & more [wo]men are [fe]male by body but fe[male] spiritually.

Comment: Bless you @iammilind

Comment: Bramhavadini's are the ladies which are allowed to follow dwija path and use yagnopavit so that they can read nigam shastras

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, is there any scripture that says women have adhikaar to chant gayatri mantra ? In case of doubt, when we cannot find scripture to support either side, we normally follow the path of people who we trust, saints, gurus and family elders. Forgetting rare exceptions like Brahmavadini's, Maitreyi & Gargi, we can safely say that people like us who are posting questions to strangers on internet, instead of asking guru, are definitely average people. And average women are not allowed to chant gayatri because they have not been initiated with brahmopadesam during upanayanam.

Comment: @ram again more comments and no scriptural proof. Proofs lie in the assertion, not in the negation. It is very easy to turn your question around and ask what scripture says that men can chant the gayatri mantra?? Still no one offers any scriptural proofs only anecdotal stories which are not scripture. And why have not the women been initiated into brahmopadesam during upanayanam? Because the priests don't do because the men in the family and caste don't want them to do! It is a vicious circle with no scriptural backing. Pure popular custom with no scriptural backing.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, and it is very easy to answer that question by looking up any number of smritis/sutras/shastras that allow and ordain men (of 3 varnas) to chant gayatri mantra after upanayanam. You said "I know of no scripture that says that women are not supposed to chant Gayatri". I'm saying "I know of no scripture that says (modern) women are allowed to chant Gayatri". Neither can be proved without research. So, when in doubt, follow elders, not your heart, especially in risky matters like mantras. Shri should ask her family acharyan instead of internet strangers before chanting.

Comment: @ram always follow your heart and not your mind....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, my heart tells me to misbehave, but my mind tells me to behave, i guess we should take your advice and listen to our hearts.

Comment: @ram that's not your heart, that's tamasic desires saying it's your heart. Gita chapter 16.

Comment: No Mantra should be chanted without initiation by Guru, either by men or women. This is mentioned in Scriptures. No one should chant also. God's names can be chanted. There are also punishments mentioned in Scriptures for not following this rule of chanting mantras without initiation.

Answer (score 11):

That the women cannot chant the Gayatri might have been a deviation from the ancient practices, that occurred in the middle times. In ancient India, women like Gargi and Maitreyi were well-versed in the scriptures. Women ***can*** chant the Gayatri mantra.

http://www.saibabaofindia.com/gayatri.htm

Hinduism has always had leaders and saints who arrive on the scene to do course corrections, like Ramanuja who declared the Vishnu mantra from a temple tower so that everyone can chant it and attain liberation.

Comment: It is incorrect to compare women of ancient times to women of the current times. Women (along with water, trees and earth) were imparted rajo dosha as a way of alleviating Indra's brahma hatya pataka. They lost the ability to chant gayatri/ do sandhya etc. once this happened.

Comment: @moonstar2001 what is rajo dosha?

Comment: @AnilKumar, it is their period of rajaswala or monthly cycle. Since sandhya-vandanam & gayatri japam must be done everyday after upanayanam, but since women are unclean on those days, and since gayatri japam must not be done when one is unclean, that is why they are not allowed to chant it. It is said that half the husband's punyam goes to wife, and half the wife's papam goes to husband. So Vedas are biased in favor of women, not men. There is no need for them to chant, since they get the fruits if only the husband chants it.

Comment: Certain things are open to people like Agamas , puranas and Itihas shastras while Nigamas (Vedas) are strictly confined to Dwijas and Bramhavaadinis. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/rules-for-wearing-yagyopavit-by-women-yes-it-is-possilbe/6668#6668    Agamas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80gama_%28Hinduism%29

Comment: Good answer. But it would be good if you can improve upon your choice of citation.

Comment: That child marriage is not allowed must have been a deviation from ancient practices. In ancient India, children would get married before they hit puberty.

Answer (score 9):

It is perfectly acceptable, and what's more, it is desirable for women to chant Gayatri Mantra. How come? 
It is because, the dharma for this Kali Yuga, is not against it. Sanatan dharma is described as the dharma of religion, and Yuga dharma as the dharma of social interaction: law, ethics, etiquette and so on.

[Swami Vivekananda on Sanatana Dharma](http://belurmath.org/complete_works_of_swami_vivekananda/volume_3/lectures_from_colombo_to_almora/first_public_lecture_in_the_east_(colombo)_frame.htm):

> We know that in our books, a clear distinction is made between two sets of truths. The one set is that which abides for ever, being built upon the nature of man, the nature of the soul, the soul's relation to God, the nature of God, perfection and so on; there are also the principles of cosmology, of the infinitude of creation, or more correctly speaking, projection, the wonderful law of cyclical procession, and so on; these are eternal principles founded upon the universal laws of nature.

How we pray to God, whether it is ethical or moral etc is governed by Yuga Dharma. The Core concepts of the soul's relation to God, Bhakti, Cycle of birth and death etc are the ones that don't change.

Religious ordination of women is not encouraged in this day and age in any religion. But that doesn't make it invalid.  In the puranic times, women committed Sati. There was a symbolism attached to it. Now if we look at it through the prism of a 21st century mind, it will seem barbaric.

Therefore, one must change with the times. Women need to take the initiative for this themselves and not look for man made approval. No need to guilt trip ourselves. Chant without fear and immerse yourself in Bhakti. God is the ultimate authority.

> The great **Saint Madhvacharya** in his Mahabharatha Tatparya Nirnaya, describes the
>   scholarly nature of Draupadi, the wife of Pandavas as
>
> Great women should study the Vedas like Krishnaa (Draupadi)
>
> > Madhava Samhite on Parashara Smriti says
> >
> > **> > yopanayanam krutwa pashcad vivaham karoti sa brahmavadini | tathaiva
> >     ya prathamata upanayanam krutwa sadya eva vivaham vidhaya tato
> >     vedamadhite sa sadyovadhuh**
>
> which means
>
> She who studies vedas after upanayana and then gets married is
>   brahmavadini, she who gets married immediately after upanayana and
>   then studies vedas is sadyovadhu
>
> This goes on to show that women were eligible to both the sacred
>   threading ceremony as well as the vedic studies in ancient times. This
>   also means that women are also eligible to Gayatri Upadesha and to
>   learn the Gayatri Mantra. Because any person who has undergone the
>   Yajnopavitam ceremony is eligible for Gayatri Upadesha.
>
> So, denying the women rights to study vedic knowledge, to 
>   Yajnopavitam Samskara and Gayatri Upadesha is un-vedic. In the vedas
>   there is not a single reference which denies the women these rights.

For those who still refuse to accept the concept of Yuga Dharma clearly mentioned in Puranas or the smriti texts, never mind. Let's turn our attention to the Vedas. Further References:

> This Veda is our only authority, and everyone has the right to it.
>   यथेमां वाचं कल्याणीमावदानि जनेभ्यः। ब्रह्मराजन्याभ्यां शूद्राय चार्याय
>   च स्वाय चारणाय॥
>
> — Thus says the **Shukla Yajur Veda (XXVI. 2)**
>
> **Atharvaveda 11.5.18**
>
> Girls should train themselves to become complete scholars and youthful
>   through Brahmcharya and then enter married life.
>
> **Rigveda 10.191.3**
>
> God says that O! man and women i am granting you these Mantras for you
>   both So, that you can think and progress together.
>
> The “Brahma” in a yajna is the best trained purohit who can correct
>   the others involved in the yajna. BRAHMAA VAA RITVIJAABHMISHAKTAMAHA –
>   Shatapatha brahmana 1.7.4.19.
>
> And.. **A woman can be a brahma as mentioned in Rigveda (8.33.-19).** “…sthree
>   hi brahmaa vibhoovidhaha” .
>
> A woman who is devoted to God is more highly regarded than a man who
>   has no such devotion, as found in the Rig-Veda: **“Yea, many a woman is
>   more firm and better than the man who turns away from Gods, and offers
>   not.” (Rig-Veda, 5.61.6)**
>
> [> Stephen Knapp calls this verse, a kind of equality that is rarely
>   found in any other religious scripture.](http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/indian-women-in-vedic-time) It is also an indication that
>   in matter of dharma, in the days of Vedic culture, women stood as a
>   decisive force in spirituality and the foundation of moral
>   development. In the Rig Veda, the idea of the family as the hub of
>   religious worship is found. In this context, women were at the heart
>   of the family structure, as wives and mothers who brought worship into
>   the center of the household activities.

"Can you show any authority from this Veda of ours that everyone has not the right to it? The Purânas, no doubt, say that a certain caste has the right to such and such a recension of the Vedas, or a certain caste has no right to study them, or that this portion of the Vedas is for the Satya Yuga and that portion is for the Kali Yuga. But, mark you, the Veda does not say so; it is only your Puranas that do so. But can the servant dictate to the master? The Smritis, Puranas, Tantras — all these are acceptable only so far as they agree with the Vedas; and wherever they are contradictory, they are to be rejected as unreliable. But nowadays we have put the Puranas on even a higher pedestal than the Vedas! The study of the Vedas has almost disappeared from Bengal. How I wish that day will soon come when in every home the Veda will be worshipped together with Shâlagrâma, the household Deity, when the young, the old, and the women will inaugurate the worship of the Veda!"

Apart from this, please see the multiple references and read the text contained in the link
https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/women-can-learn-the-vedas-affirm-vedas/

Therefore, whichever way we look at it, whether we are basing our beliefs on the sayings of great saints and philosophers, smriti texts or in fact the Vedas, it is perfectly allowed for women to recite Gayatri Mantra. Happy Chanting!

Answer (score 5):

In the book, *[Hindu Dharma: The Universal Way of Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8172760558)*, [Swami Chandrasekarendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) explains why some of the Hindu samskāras are not prescribed for women and people belonging to the fourth varna.

> **What about Women?**
>
> I said that the twice-born must perform sandhyavandana with the
> wellbeing of women and other jatis in mind. I also explained why all
> samskaras are not prescribed for the fourth varna. Now we must
> consider the question of women, why they do not have such rituals and
> samskāras.
>
> Even though we perform the punyāha-vacana and nāmakaraņa of
> newborn girls and celebrate their first birthday, we do not conduct
> their caula and upanayana nor the other samskāras or vows laid down
> for brahmacārins. Of course, they have the marriage samskāra. But in
> other rites like sacrifices the main part is that of the husband,
> though she (the wife) has to be by his side. In aupāsana alone does a
> woman have a part in making oblations in the sacred fire.
>
> **Why is it so?**
>
> The rites performed before a child is born are intended for the birth
> of a male child (niseka, pumsavana, simanta). Does it mean, as
> present-day reformers and women's libbers say, that Hindu women were
> downgraded and kept in darkness?
>
> What reason did I mention for the
> fourth varna not having to perform many of the samskaras? That these
> were not necessary considering their vocations and the fact that they
> can work for the welfare of the world without the physical and mental
> benefits to be derived from the samskāras. If they also spend their
> time in Vedic learning and in sacrifices, what will happen to their
> duties? **So most of the samskaras are not necessary for them. They
> reach the desired goal without these rites by carrying out their
> duties. "Svakarmana tam abhyarcya siddhim vindati mānavah", so says
> the Gita** [[18.46](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/46)]. I have spoken to you about this earlier.
>
> Just as
> society is divided according to occupations and the samskaras are
> correspondingly different, so too there are differences between men
> and women in domestic life. Running a household means different types
> of work, keeping the house clean, bringing up the children, etc. By
> nature women can these chores better than men. If they also take an
> active part in rituals, what happen to such work? Each by serving her
> husband and by looking after her household becomes inwardly pure.
>
> In
> truth there is no disparity between men and women, nor are women
> discriminated against as present-day reformers allege. Work is divided
> for the proper maintenance not only of the home but the nation on the
> whole; and care has been taken not to have any duplication. There is
> no intention of lowering the status of any section in this division of
> labour.
>
> The body, in the case of certain people, is meant to preserve
> the mantras and there are samskāras which have the purpose of making
> it worthy of the same. Why should the same rituals be prescribed for
> those who do not have such tasks to carry out? Glassware to be sent by
> railway parcel is specially taken care of since it is fragile. Even
> greater care is taken in dispatching kerosene or petrol. If the same
> precautions are not taken in transporting other goods, does it mean
> that they are poorly thought of? Astronauts are kept in isolation
> before being sent up in space and after their return. Mantras have
> their own radiation that is even more powerful than what is found in
> space. If you appreciate this fact, you will understand why Brahmins
> are separated from the rest and special samskāras prescribed for them.
>
> The body of a Brahmin (male) is involved in the nurturing of mantras.
> So from the time of conception itself it is to be made pure through
> samskāras like pumsavana, simanta, and so on. There are samskāras with
> the same objective also after the boy child is born.
>
> The vocations
> have to be properly divided for the welfare of mankind. If everybody
> paid attention to this fact, instead of talking of rights, it would be
> realised that the sāstras have not discriminated against women or any
> of the jātis.