# Consequence of women chanting mantras

Tags: belief, mantras, women

What are the consequences of women chanting mantras? Do scriptures say anything about this?

Comment: Related [Why are women not allowed to chant the Gayatri mantra?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9200/3500)

Comment: The above question answers why women are not permitted to chant mantra.But I like to know the ill effects of chanting the mantra with reference form the scriptures.

Answer (score 8):

Let me share with you some of my findings.

**Find 1**.:The 108 names of Skanda(Karthikeya) given by Maharshi Viswamitra is found in the [Skanda Puranam](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana10.html).Refer to the Phalasruti(of reading the Ashtottara Stotram) given below.

> Sage Viswamitra recited the following Ashtottara Namavali (108 names)
>   about Skanda Deva on the most significant day of Kartika Pournami of
>   which Kartikaya is fond of:...
>
> Phalasruti: Those who recite the Ashtottara of Kartikeya become
>   fearless, contented, and happy; **a pregnant woman** reads or hears
>   the Ashtottara would be blessed with a son of virtue and fortune; and
>   if **unmarried girls** read they are sure to secure ideal husbands.

**Find 2**. Refer to the Phalasruti of the Brahma Vaivarta Puranam as found on [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=23) page:

> ....It demolishes of Vighnas (obstacles of any kind) and yields fruits
>   of performing Yagnas, Tirtha Darshanas, Vratas and Tapasya. There is
>   no exaggeration in saying that reading this Purana excels �Veda
>   Pathana�. **Any unfortunate woman reading this** would result in
>   prosperity to herself and her husband. The Purana Shravana or Pathana
>   blesses the **person** concerned with good progeny, good wife /
>   **husband**, and name and fame. It relieves of diseases to the diseased, shackles from imprisonment, dangers from the victims of
>   great risks, and panic to those experiencing fright etc.

**Find 3**: From [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=15) chapter of the Brahma Vaivarta Purana

> -Devi Savitri is the mother of Vedas whom Brahma Deva worshipped first followed by all the Devas. A reputed King of Madradesha called
>   Ashwapati and his queen Malati whose qualities of virtue, charity and
>   devotion brought them fame in the contemporary times but had
>   unfortunately no children. **Maharshi Vasishta gave �Upadesha�
>   (Instruction) of Gayatri Mantra and the royal couple performed sincere
>   �japa� (repetitive muttering of Mantra)** and worship but to no avail;
>   they shifted to Pushkara Kshetra and intensified their devotion.

So,it seems women are allowed to recite Mantras,Scriptures etc.

As & when i find more relevant references i'll keep updating my answer with them.