# Why don't Sudras wear a sacred thread?

Tags: scripture, rituals, caste-system, brahmins, yagnopavitam

According to caste-system based on Manu-smriti, only the first three categories i.e.,  Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas are allowed to wears the sacred thread.

Why are Sudras not entitled to wear the sacred thread and learn Vedas?

Comment: Why are school teachers not given guns, but only police are given guns ? It depends on nature of people. The level of penance and rules to be followed are high for those who wear sacred thread. Sudras are exempt from this because the jobs they are inclined to do will not allow them to follow those rules e.g. you cannot expect a construction worker to do sandhya vandanam thrice a day.

Comment: See [my answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14709/2995) to [Why are women not allowed to chant the Gayatri mantra?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9200/2995)

Answer (score 5):

- When a person wears a sacred thread he must follow certain rules & should remain pious all the time. Everyone can't follow all these rules.
- In the past era, The people were divided in different Varna according to the kind of the work they did. Since Sudras were the people who did odd jobs. That's why they not used to wear sacred thread.
- But now there are many Communities like [Gayatri Pariwar](http://www.awgp.org/) , follwers of these communities wear The sacred Thread irrespective of their varna or castes.
- This should be very clear that now whoever wants to wear sacred threads may wear it, if he is ready to follow the rituals.

Answer (score 0):

Sudhras are having only clan in their caste, but they doesn't have gothra to marry in procedures of rituals that's why they shouldn't wear and touch scared thread

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).