# Are women allowed to undergo upanayana?

Tags: vedas, women

It is generally accepted that only males can undergo upanayana and that women do not have the right it. However, according to the [Wikipedia article on upanayana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana#Women_and_Upanayana), women in some regions are allowed to undergo upanayana. Wikipedia also says that certain texts specifically have injunctions for women to study the Vedas:

> In some regions, in modern times, boys and girls undergo the tradition of Upanayana initiation when they start their formal schooling.[20] In ancient and medieval eras, texts such as Harita Dharmasutras, Asvalayana Grhya Sutra and Yama smriti suggest women could begin Vedic studies after the Upanayana rite of passage.[6][21][22]
>
> Girls who decided to become a student underwent the Upanayana rite of passage, at the age of 8, and thereafter were called Brahmavadini. They wore a thread or upper garment over their left shoulder.[6] Those girls who chose not to go to a gurukul were called Sadyovadhu (literally, one who marries straight). However, the Sadyovadhu, too, underwent a step during the wedding rituals, where she would complete Upanayana, and thereafter wear her upper garment (saree) over her left shoulder.[6] This interim symbolic Upanayana rite of passage for a girl, before her wedding, is described in multiple texts such as the Gobhila Gryha Sutra verse 2.1.19 and some Dharmasutras.[23]

Is Wikipedia right to say that women are allowed to study the Vedas and undergo upanayana?

P.S. It would be appreciated if any of you guys could quote from scriptures like Harita Dharmasutras, Asvalayana Grhya Sutra,Gobhila Gryha Sutra, Yama smriti or any other text.

Comment: According to Manu and other Smritis not allowed.

Comment: No. Women are not eligible to chant Vedas due to their body parts. So no Upanayanam.

Comment: @Parikshitha Lol ik u told me That's why I am seeing whether this can be refuted.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17134/7853

Comment: @Parikshitha My aunt wears sacred thread and she chant vedic mantras as well.

Comment: @Parikshitha what body parts.has to do with this ?