# Are there sects that prohibit their women from uttering "Om"?

Tags: women, om

There is a chap on u-tube that says women should not say "Om" - they should say "am".

Comment: All Vedanta sects...

Comment: @Ikshvaku its false claim and i.have discussed it in detail in my posts. The fact that rig Veda has about 30 women seers dismisses all such claims of them not being entitled to chant Vedas.

Comment: @Ikshvaku all these are already acquired. I am ready for an open challenge from anyone.

Comment: @SK yes all Vedanta sects prohibit ... Also shudras.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The Harita and Yama smriti do allow Brahmavadini women to chant. But there are no Brahmavadini women today.

Comment: I think the reverse of this 'which sects allow their women to chant Om/mantras?' maybe a better question.

Comment: Obviously Anuradha Paudwal's sect does :-)   @sv.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Harita is quoted only to show that women did in the past. Then we have quotes from gobhila and other sutras too.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I heard this from Vedic scholars.

Comment: @Ikshvaku then quote those Vedic scholars the example of Mandana mishra wife who mastered Vedas and vedangas. Also quote the gobhila grhya sutra.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Can you please provide the Gobhila Grihya Sutra verses?

Comment: @Ikshvaku https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17134/7853

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Ok. I posted a new question about it: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32350/11726

Comment: Not just women, it is said all Grihastyas shouldn't chant "OM" *alone* as it is said it gives vairagya (dispassion) on repeated chanting. But i'm not aware of scriptural reference for this.

Comment: It would be great if you ask reference from vedas and not from puranas or smritis

Comment: 'chap on u-tube' - great source !

Comment: "great source" thx for the compliment.

Answer (score 7):

**It is NOT a question of sect.The Smiritis and Puranas prohibit the utterance of OM for all who are not having the sacred thread**.

In the commentary of sloka 29 chapter 289 of Santiparva of Mahabharata, Haridasa Siddhantabagish writes:

> **Shudras and females are not allowed to utter OM, because the Sruti (The Vedas) prohibits it ..सावित्रीं प्रणवं यजुरर्लक्ष्मीं स्त्री-शूद्रयोर्नेच्छन्ति इति श्रुत्या निषेधात्.**[SAVITRIM PRANAVAM YAJUR LAKSHMIM STREE- SUDRAYOR NECHCHHANTI ITI SRUTYA NISHEDHAT]
>
> Srmadbhagavam says (1/4/25) that "trayi" (which means both the A-U-M and the three vedas, should not be heard by **women** and the sudras.
>
> In the Pranavakalpa of Skandapurana(Chapter 1, sloka 17-8), Lord Shiva says to Goddess Parvati : **O Devi, being a female you are not allowed to utter OM.**

Saints like Sri Ramakrishna(Reference:Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leelamrita by Vaikunthanath Sannyal), Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath(Reference-Pita-Putra by Sri Omkarnath) did not allow the sudras and women to utter OM.

And there are different religious restrictions on males also, especially on brahmins. No religion can accept 'Go as you like' and 'Do as your like' approaches until the aspirant attains Para-bhakti that frees him or her from all bondages and bindings

Comment: please tell me it ain't so about Siva :-) - @Partha Banerjee if anything is an interpolation, this has to be one.

Comment: @SK that i dont know. i dont have the authority. I dont find any cruelty in this.

Comment: @SK I have quoted the reference. There is another reference in a collection of His sayings by Satish chandra Mukhopadhyaya, as referred to in Pita-Putra mentioned above.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17134/7853

Comment: Please add transliteration of these Sanskrit verse because some users don't understand the script

Comment: @KrishnaShweta given....