# Are Brahmavadini women allowed to marry and have sex?

Tags: women, sex, brahmavadini

Brahmavadini women are women who learn the Vedas, recite mantras, and do Yajnas, as stated [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17134/11726).

My question is, can they marry and have sex with their husbands?

According to the *translator's note* of the *[Mitakshara](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/103)*, they can:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its not different for male and female. Also those brahma jijnasu men have the same thing. Brahma jijnasu people dont have horns on their head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are Brahmavadini women allowed to marry and have sex?

**Yes, and in fact, I think they are required to as a duty in marriage.**

From the [*Mahabharata*](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03097.htm) on the story between Agastya and Lopamudra:

> After a considerable time, O king, the illustrious Rishi [Agastya] one day
>   beheld Lopamudra, blazing in ascetic splendour come up after the bath
>   in her season. And pleased with the girl, for her services, her
>   purity, and self control, as also with her grace and beauty, he
>   summoned her for marital intercourse.

Comment: So are men required to please their spouse

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes they are